# Visual studio code: How to create multilines indented snippets?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I try to create multilines snippet like so:

```
"mySnippet": {
        "prefix": "test",
        "body": [
            "<div>",
                "<p></p>",
            "</div>"
        ]
    }
```

But it's not indented...

[Reading the doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets) doesnt' help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the indentation inside the second string element of the body array:

```
"mySnippet": {
        "prefix": "test",
        "body": [
            "<div>",
            "  <p></p>",
            "</div>"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: is there another way of doing it with CDATA?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\t`for <kbd>TAB</kbd> on each line:

```
"table": {
    "prefix": "table",
    "body": [
        "<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">",
            "\t<tr>",
                "\t\t<td>",
                    "\t\t\t<i class=\"fas fa-bullhorn\"></i>",
                "\t\t</td>",
                "\t\t<td>",
                    "\t\t\t${1:element}",
                "\t\t</td>",
            "\t</tr>",
        "</table>"
    ],
    "description": "Text with a bullhorn icon on the left"
}
```